# Stopped Jobs error upon logout

Tags: server, 14.04, cron, process

There are times when I attempt to `logout` of SSH and I get something along the lines of:

`There are stopped jobs`

Not knowing what this is, I end up force quitting putty with the exit button in the upper right. Doesn't seem to affect anything as I can login every time no issues.

**My questions are:**

What am I doing to cause certain "jobs" to stop?

How do I view them both stopped and running "jobs"?

How do I rectify the situation in order for me to `logout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It exists the command `jobs` that shows you the running jobs and the suspended ones.

```
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 12
[2]-  Running                 sleep 10 &
```

When you find a suspended (Stopped) job you can put in foreground with `fg` or with `%1`( if it is with the label `[1]`) and wait that the process continue till the end.

You can suspend an active job with `CTRL Z`
You can interrupt it with `CTRL C`
You can execute a command and put it in background with `command &`  (e.g. `sleep 10 &`): the shell will execute the command, put it in background, and give you the prompt.

You can also kill with `kill %1` (always if it is the 1st job of the shell)
In this case if you write `kill %1` it will answer :

```
[1]+  Terminated              sleep 12
```

If you want you can write `jobs -l` . E.g:

```
[3]+ 21921 Stopped                 sleep 16
```

To kill this job you can use or `kill %3` or `kill 21921`, where `21921` is the `PID` of the process.

When you have no suspended jobs you can exit without problem from the shell (and in this case from the ssh connection)

Note: Only in extreme cases you can use `kill -9 %3` or `kill -9 21921`. This will abruptly close the process (job) without giving it the time to exit normally. (It can avoid to free memory, socket, close files ...)

Comment: I attempted 'kill %1' with no success.

Comment: when you write `jobs` in the shell, is there a `[1]+  Stopped somecommand` line?

Comment: Yes, do you need to actually type [1]+ to kill